# ExpressJS/NodeJS and Object Orientated Programming

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, oop, design-patterns

I'm new to the industry, but it seems like most companies seem to test/emphasize OOP knowledge heavily during the interview process even when their stack is based mostly in javascript/NodeJS/typescript.

I'm confused how this would be applicable to developing backend applications/APIs using a framework like ExpressJS?

For example, a sample GET route in pseudo code:

```
app.get('/', async(req, res) => { 
  const exampleData = await database.querySomething()
  res.send(exampleData)
})
```

It seems to me the coding style for creating these REST APIs is somewhat procedural. E.g. receive a request, make some database action or query based on the parameters, add in calculations/data wrangling, send back the final data.

Where does OOP come into play? What would be a use case for OOP in back end nodejs applications?

Comment: In these three lines of code you are using methods on three objects. Maybe companies are hoping you can write something more complex than a route handler.

Comment: You'll probably be using an ORM framework such as Sequelize or Mongoose, and you'll probably have to do more than just CRUD treatment on those data.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. Sorry if this seems obvious, but is it considered normal to mix in functional/procedural with OOP in javascript applications then? For instance, building helpers/libraries with some providing just pure functions whereas others are model-based?

Answer (score 0):

You need to focus on the language, i.e Javascript, and not Express when you come to OOP concept.

One of the best ressource on the web is the MDN website for JS language. [Start here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I guess the main source of my confusion is what is considered OOP. For instance, all Node.JS applications that I've come across use a mix of OOP/functional/procedural styles. Hence, I'm struggling to find use cases of pure OOP Nodejs programs.

Comment: That perfecly normal, you will find many and many new uses case with the time.

Comment: For OOP you need to define a class with the new ES6 keyword 'class'. 
I you find anser handy, dont forget to validate, I 'm still thinking it's the good answer

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code in es6 or use frameworks which fully supports oops approach.Check out frameworks like - [fortjs](http://fortjs.info/), [nestjs](https://nestjs.com/) etc.

e.g - A controller in fortjs would look like -

```
export class UserController extends Controller {

    @defaultWorker()
    async getUsers() {
        const service = new UserService();
        return jsonResult(service.getUsers());
    }

    @worker([HTTP_METHOD.Post])
    @route("/")
    async addUser() {
        const user = {
            name: this.body.name,
            gender: this.body.gender,
            address: this.body.address,
            emailId: this.body.emailId,
            password: this.body.password
        };
        const service = new UserService();
        const newUser = service.addUser(user);
        return jsonResult(newUser, HTTP_STATUS_CODE.Created);
    }

}
```